# Is it possible to find the angles of an irregular quadrilateral when the area and side lengths are given?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

This was a question that I was asked by my math teacher at the end of last semester as a fun thought question and I have spent a while on it but I still cannot find an equation that would solve this. I have tried finding a system of equations with law of cosines and law of sines and Heron's formula but still can't find something. Please let me know if it is even possible. If it is, what would the process be?

Comment: You actually have a system of equations for two opposite angles. When you solve it, the formula for the cosine of any angle admits two roots.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not uniquely. Imagine a kite with sides $a,b,b,a$ in rotational order. The area is not hard to render as $ab\sin\theta$ where $\theta$ measures either of the congruent angles where an $a$ side meets a $b$ side (divide the quadrilateral in half along its mirror libe and consider each triangle). But that means the area is the same for two supplementary values of $\theta$, and except for the obvious degeneracies given by $\theta=90°$ and $a=b$, the kites will have two different shapes. In some cases (e.g. $a=3, b=4, \theta = 30°$ or $150°$) you can even have the quadrilateral concave for the acute $\theta$ and convex for the obtuse $\theta$.

Let us look at a more general case. It is assumed here that  solutions exist where the quadrilateral does not cross itself, which avoids complications with having to use negative signs for opposite orientations of areas and angles.

The sides of quadrilateral $ABCD$ are rendered as $AB=a,BC=b,CD=c,DA=d$ in rotational order, with area $K$. Wlog we can cyclically permute the sides so that $a+b\ge c+d$, which assures that the angle at $B$ will be between $0°$ and $180°$ (that angle is convex). We can therefore solve for this angle by rendering its cosine. We will, however, allow for concave solutions.

We define $\angle A$ as the quadrilateral angle at $A$ and similarly for the other vertices.

Draw the diagonal $\overline{AC}$ and apply the Law of Cosines to each of the two resulting triangles to find the diagonal length $l$:

$l^2=a^2+b^2-2ab\cos\angle B$

$l^2=c^2+d^2-2cd\cos\angle D$

These lengths must agree so we can derive the difference equation

$ab\cos\angle B-cd\cos\angle D=\frac12(a^2+b^2-c^2-d^2) \text{     Eq. 1}$

At the same time the area of the quadrilateral must be the sum of the two triangle areas. Note that the "sum" could be a difference of magnitudes if the $\theta_2$ vertex is concave, which would eventually show up as a reflex angle and thus a negative sine value.

$ab\sin\angle B+cd\sin\angle D=2K \text{     Eq. 2}$

**Bretschneider's Formula**

Suppose we square Eqs. 1 and 2, and add them up:

$a^2b^2(\cos^2\angle B+\sin^2\angle B)-2abcd(\cos\angle B\cos\angle D-\sin\angle B\sin\angle D)+c^2d^2(\cos^2\angle D+\sin^2\angle D)=\frac14(a^2+b^2-c^2-d^2)^2+4K^2$

The trigonometric expressions above may be simplified using standard identities to give:

$a^2b^2-2abcd\cos(\angle B+\angle D)+c^2d^2=\frac14(a^2+b^2-c^2-d^2)^2+4K^2$

This is, essentially, Bretschneider's formula: a relation between the area of a quadrilateral, the lengths of its sides, and the sum of two opposing angles. Usually it is solved for area, but here we are solving for angles. Thus we render the formula into the following, where $\Sigma=\angle B+\angle D$:

$\cos\Sigma=\dfrac{4(a^2b^2+c^2d^2)-(a^2+b^2-c^2-d^2)^2-16K^2}{8abcd}\text{     Eq. 3}$

Note that a solution exists only if the numerator has an absolute value less than or equal to the denominator, thus limiting the range of possible areas given a set of edge lengths.

The sum of opposing angles may be anything from $0°$ to $360°$, so Eq. 3 implies two roots for this sum:

$\Sigma_-=\arccos(\cos\Sigma), \Sigma_+=360°-\arccos(\cos\Sigma)\text{     Eqs. 4a, 4b}$

where the cosine of the angle sum is given by Eq. 3.

**The main assault**

We can now eliminate $\angle D$ from Eq. 1 or 2 to get an equation for $\angle B$ alone. We choose Eq. 1, with an eye towards getting the *cosine* of $\angle B$ which is known to lie between $0°$ and $180°$:

$ab\cos\angle B-cd\cos(\Sigma-\angle B)=\frac12(a^2+b^2-c^2-d^2)$

$ab\cos\angle B-cd\cos\Sigma\cos\angle B-cd\sin\Sigma\sin\angle B=\frac12(a^2+b^2-c^2-d^2)$

We isolate the odd power of $\sin\angle B$ and square, leading to a quadratic equation for $\cos\angle B$:

$cd\sin\Sigma\sin\angle B=ab\cos\angle B-cd\cos\Sigma\cos\angle B-\frac12(a^2+b^2-c^2-d^2)$

$c^2d^2(1-\cos^2\Sigma)(1-\cos^2\angle B)=((ab-cd\cos\Sigma)\cos\angle B-\frac12(a^2+b^2-c^2-d^2))^2\text{     Eq. 5}$

If solutions exist, then this quadratic equation will have two roots for $\cos\angle B$. For a non self-crossing quadrilateral the smaller $\angle B$ and thus the larger root for $\cos\angle B$ will be associated with the $\Sigma_-$ root from Eq. 4a, and the smaller root for $\cos\angle B$ will be associated with the $\Sigma_+$ root from Eq. 4b.

Once we have thus obtained roots for $\angle B$ and $\angle D=\Sigma-\angle B$, we can solve for the length of the dividing diagonal and then all the angles of both triangles, from which we then get the remaining quadrilateral angles.

**Plugging in numbers**

The method is illustrated with an example, which I shamelessly rigged to produce a solution easy to recognize and one that is a bit less trivial.

We render $a=5, b=5, c=3, d=1, K=9$.  Given that two opposite sides differ by $4$ and the remaining sides are $3$ and $5$, might you be able to guess one solution (think $3-4-5$ right triangle)?

First apply the Bretschnieder formulation. We have

$\cos\Sigma =\dfrac{4×(5^2×5^2+3^2×1^2)-(5^2+5^2-3^1-1^2)^21(16×9^2)}{8×5×5×3×1}=-\dfrac{360}{600}=-\dfrac35$

$\Sigma_-=\arccos(-3/5)\approx 126°52'12''$

$\Sigma_+=360°\arccos(-3/5)\approx 233°07'48''$

Next plus the known value of $\cos{\Sigma}$ into the quadratic Eq. 5:

$9×
[1-(9/25)](1-\cos^2\angle B)=[(25+3×(3/5))\cos\angle B-\frac12(25+25-9-1)]^2$

$4525\cos^2\angle B-6700\cos\angle B+2464=0$

$\cos\angle B\in\{4/5,616/905\}$

By our association rule we then have

$\angle B_-=\arccos(4/5)\approx 36°52'12'', \angle D_- = \arccos(-3/5)-\arccos(4/5)=90°$

$\angle B_+=\arccos(616/905)\approx 47°06'16'',\angle D_+ =360°-\arccos(-3/5)-\arccos(616/905) \approx 186°01'32''$

Note that the second solution is concave at $D$, so when we solve the triangular components we need to subtract rather than add angular magnitudes.

We now go to the triangle-solution part of the problem to resolve all the quadrilateral angles. First consider our convex root for which we have found $\angle B_-\approx 36°52'12'$, $\angle D_-=90°$. Apply the Pythagorean Theorem to $\triangle ACD$ to get the length $l$ of diagonal $\overline{AC}$, from which $l=\sqrt{10}$. With all sides of $\triangle ABC$ and $\angle D$ known, we apply the Law of Sines (or SOH CAH TOA) to that triangle to get the remaining angles, thus $\angle DAC\approx 71°33'54", \angle DCA\approx 18°26'56"$. Similarly the sides of isosceles $\triangle ABC$ and $\angle B$ are known, so we can calculate $\angle BAC=\angle CAB\approx 71°33'54''$. Then the quadrilateral angles at $A$ and $C$ are

$\angle A=\angle BAC+\angle DAC\approx 143°07'48''$

$\angle C=\angle BCA+\angle DCA=90°$

Thus for this root we have the summary solution

$AB=5,BC=5,CD=3,DA=1,K=9\to \angle A\approx 143°07'48'',\angle B\approx 36°52'12'', \angle C=90°, \angle D = 90°.$ (a right trapezoid)

Now turn to our second root, described by $\angle B_+\approx 47°06'16'',\angle D_+ =\approx 186°01'32''$. This quadrilateral is concave at $D$, but the Law of Cosines for both triangles still gives the correct diagonal length. The isosceles triangle $ABC$ is simpler to work with:

$AC=\sqrt{5^2+5^2-2×5×5(616/905)}=\sqrt{2890/181}$

We then apply the Law of Sines to each triangle as before:

$\angle BAC=\angle CAB=\arcsin(5\sin\angle B/\sqrt{2890/181})\approx 66°26'52''$

With the concavity at $D$, $\triangle $ADC$ will give negative angles:

$\angle DAC=\arcsin(3\sin\angle D/\sqrt{2890/181})\approx-4°31'13''$

$\angle DCA=\arcsin(1\sin\angle D/\sqrt{2890/181})\approx-1°30'19''$

$\angle A=\angle BAC+\angle DAC\approx 61°55'39''$

$\angle C=\angle BCA+\angle DCA=64°56'33''$

So for the concave root:

$AB=5,BC=5,CD=3,DA=1,K=9\to \angle A\approx 61°55'39'',\angle B\approx 47°06'16'', \angle C\approx64°56'33'', \angle D \approx186°01'32''.$

Comment: What about for a quadrilateral with all unique side lengths? I feel like it should be possible but I still have not been able to work in out on paper.

Comment: The same thing happens, just the algebra is a lot harder. You can shape the quadrilateral so it's inscribed in a circle, which is the _maximum_ area (like the kite with $\theta=90°$). Then if you pull on two opposing vertices making the diagonal longer or push making the diagonal shorter, the area goes down either way. It's never a 1:1 function.

Comment: This looks like there are at most finitely many solutions, or maybe even at most 2. Is this true in general? Or are there situations where there is a continuous deformation that preserves area and all edge length?

Comment: There are either two possible configurations for a quadrilateral that has a set area and side length. However, each quadrilateral with set side lengths will have an area value that is only possible with one configuration.

Comment: I think I caught all the minor errors at last.

Answer (score 1):

For a rhombus there are two extreme positions where the area is $0$. So for a quadrilateral with sides almost equal ( but all unequal if you prefer) there are two extreme positions where the area is almost $0$. So deforming from a large area to those positions you  find two distinct deformations with same area.  From the largest area to the smallest one some values are achieved exactly twice.  See also
[Bretschneider's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrilateral#Trigonometric_formulas)